# Elastic Beanstalk does not deploy the app after autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-auto-scaling

So because of  `NetworkOut < 2000000 for 1 datapoints within 5 minutes` policy in the autoscaling group my instance got terminated. Then it created a new instance but did not redeploy my app on the new instance. Why is that? Shouldn't it be automatically deploying the app on the new instance?

By the way, I am using Elastic Beanstalk and the flask backend.

If you can help me figure out why it is happening, then that would be awesome?

Comment: Can you ssh to the instance, and check it logs in `/var/logs`?

Comment: @Marcin sorry for the late comment but yes the problem was not AWS deploying but the problem was in the code itself. I have to do things manually to make it work!